# Grabing variables from string

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I want to get multiple variables out of a string. Let's imagine that the string is `"rgb(74, 29, 87)"`. How can I get the R, G and B values out of the string?

Is there any way I could do something simple like:

```js
const str = rgb(74, 29, 87);
const color = str.grab("rgb({R}, {G}, {B})");

console.log(color);
// Outputs: { R: 74, G: 29, B: 87 }
```

Or at least get the variables in an array instead of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing built-in, but you should be able to build a regular expression based on the pattern string and match the input against it:

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

function grab(str, pattern) {
    let re = escapeRegExp(pattern).replace(/\\{(\w+)\\}/g, ($0, $1) =>
        '(?<' + $1 + '>.+?)'
    )
    return (str.match(re) || {}).groups;
}

const str = 'rgb(74, 29, 87)'
const color = grab(str, "rgb({R}, {G}, {B})");

console.log(color);
// Outputs: { R: 74, G: 29, B: 87 }
```

(assuming an engine that supports [named capture groups](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_named_capture_groups))